# Por que mi background de la modal no desaparece?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

Espero puedan ayudarme, tengo este codigo en el app.blade:
cuando quito el @include('layouts.mensajes') se desaparece el background, pero ya no me genera los mensajes de toastr. Como puedo resolver esto? y cuando dejo el @include al momento de tener una ventana modal hace su proceso adecuadamente pero no desaparece el background de color gris, el detalle es que no puedo seguir haciendo nada ya que me bloquea toda la ventana

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
               <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
          <div class="container">
              @include('layouts.mensajes')
              @yield('content')
          </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

tengo mi archivo mensajes que estoy incluyendo en este archivo:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

  <script>
    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
    toastr.success('Guardado con Exito', 'Trypode Systems', {
        "progressBar": false,
        "timeOut": "2000"
      });
    @endif
    @if ($message = Session::get('warning'))
    toastr.warning('Editado con Exito', 'Trypode Systems', {
        "progressBar": false,
        "timeOut": "2000"
      });
    @endif
    @if ($message = Session::get('danger'))
    toastr.error('Eliminado con Exito', 'Trypode Systems', {
        "progressBar": false,
        "timeOut": "2000"
      });
    @endif
  </script>
```

Existencia
                Precio
                Cantidad
              
            
            
              
                
              
              
                
              
              
                
              
            
            
              Agregar
              Cancelar

Comment: No veo modal por ninguna parte en tu codigo

Comment: lo agregue, pero realmente no es problema de la modal, lo que me da problema es el @Include al momento de colocarlo, ya no me funciona inlcuso el javascript y cuando lo coloco, las modales se quedan trabadas